# Is there any point in adding 'npm' in the 'dependencies' field in 'package.json'?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I saw this somewhere, inside `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...,
  "npm": "^6.1.0",
  ...
}
```

Is there any point in this?

Will `npm` update itself as a result of this?

If yes, will it be able to do so if its current version is lower than 6?

Comment: Usually, this should be in `devDependencies` instead of `dependencies`...

Comment: @IanMacDonald: Thank you. And the point in putting it there? It still feels like a chicken & egg paradox if you know what I mean.

Comment: It helps to define the expected environment. If you had `npm 5` installed and something didn't work, you may not have any hints as to why if this weren't present. With this described here, it will let you know that this project should be built with `npm ^6.1.0`. Normally, however, you could probably just put that in a README.

Comment: @IanMacDonald The `engines` field is the correct place to define the environment; not `devDependencies`; see my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the normal practice for packages. This will not affect your global installation of `npm`.

If you wish to specify which version of `npm` your package requires to be installed, the `engines` field in the `package.json` is the proper place to put it. From [the npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json.html#engines):

> You can also use the “engines” field to specify which versions of npm are capable of properly installing your program. For example:
>
> ```
> { "engines" : { "npm" : "~1.0.20" } }
> ```
>
> Unless the user has set the `engine-strict` config flag, this field is advisory only and will only produce warnings when your package is installed as a dependency.

`npm` will not prevent installation of packages with a different version of `npm` listed in `engines`, but it will warn in the console that it's requesting a different version of `npm` than what you're using.

The only purpose of installing `npm` as a dependency would be if it's a package that somehow needs to use `npm`'s API directly (like a `node_modules/` analyzer, or something like that).